# Multi-page export in *.tiff and other image formats using Export Map?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, geotiff-tiff, export, data-driven-pages

Is there a way to export multiple maps in *.tiff using "Export Map" and setting Data Driven Pages?

Because Data Drive Page work in "Export map" only with PDF.

Answer (score 6):

You can export to other formats, however you will have to use python/arcpy module:

> [How to export Data Driven Pages to other formats using ArcMap:](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00sm00000008000000)
>
> You can use a simple arcpy.mapping script to export Data Driven Pages
>   to formats other than PDF. This example shows how to export Data
>   Driven Pages to a series of PNG image files.

```
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
for pageNum in range(1, mxd.dataDrivenPages.pageCount + 1):
  mxd.dataDrivenPages.currentPageID = pageNum
  arcpy.mapping.ExportToPNG(mxd, r"C:\Temp\ParcelAtlas_Page" + str(pageNum) + ".png")
del mxd
```

You may use the [ExportToTIFF](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00s300000009000000) method instead.

Answer (score 3):

I would use a Python snippet to do this via the Python window. The following is adapted from the [ESRI help page on data-driven pages](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/DataDrivenPages/00s300000030000000/):

```
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")

for page_number in range(1, mxd.dataDrivenPages.pageCount + 1):
    mxd.dataDrivenPages.currentPageID = page_number
    print "Exporting page {0} of {1}".format(str(mxd.dataDrivenPages.currentPageID), str(mxd.dataDrivenPages.pageCount))
    arcpy.mapping.ExportToTIFF(mxd, r"C:\Temp\map_" + str(page_number) + ".tiff")

del mxd
```

This can just be copied and pasted into the window and run. Remember to change the path of the output directory to **one that already exists**.

Comment: Ok the function works fine, but I need also to export as geotiff, but argis say:

    Runtime error <type 'exceptions.TypeError'>: PageLayoutObject: Error in executing ExportToTIFF

I've read in other topic that some options is only available if the export is maked in data frame, not in page layout. In the Data Driven I've set a 500x500 m grid, and in layout view I also have set the size of the view explicitly to display only one cell at a time. 
The problem is that if I leave the layout view is impossible export a cell at a time, but exports everything that is displayed.

Solutions?